# Отображения большого количества данных из базы данных

Tags: android, sqlite

Подскажите, как лучше отобразить в списке данные из базы SQLite, что бы не было никаких тормозов, при количестве элементов в списке около 100к?

Comment: recyclerview пробовали?

Comment: @andreich да пробовал, ели читать в память все данные, то очень долго грузиться список, вопрос наверное скорее в том, будет ли достаточно например cursorAdapter-а

Comment: Для начала я бы задумался - а надо ли пользователю реально смотреть все 100к данных? он же прокручивать запарится...

Comment: А если читать блоками по N элементов? А потом подгружать необходимое. @Akina собственно да

Comment: @Akina У нас справа отображаются сколл, с помощью которого можно перейти быстро к любому элементу списка https://github.com/timusus/RecyclerView-FastScroll/raw/master/screenshot.png, если грузить по 20 например, то очень долго весь список грузится и скачет скролл, если выбрать цифру по больше то долго в память грузятся данные

Comment: @АксеновВладимир ответил

Answer (score 4):

Это неважно как отображать через `RecyclerView` или `ListView`, главное чтобы источником данных для списка был `Cursor` полученный в результате запроса к БД - в терминах Android - это означает адаптер использующий в качестве данных `Cursor`.

При таком подходе из базы будет "дергаться" всегда только необходимое для отображения количество записей к тому же если правильно реализовать методы `newView()` и `bindView()` адаптера, то ранее подгруженные записи будут кэшироваться.

В случае `ListView` это один из вариантов `CursorAdapter` - если запрос простой, то вполне подойдет `SimpleCursorAdapter`, при этом `Cursor`'ом лучше управлять через `CursorLoader`, который будет управлять открытием и закрытием курсора.

В случае `RecyclerView` все чуточку сложнее, поскольку так уж получилось, что у `RecyclerView` нет коробочного адаптера, который "питается" из `Cursor`'а, я бы рекомендовал использовать либу [RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://github.com/androidessence/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter), впрочем схожих реализаций подобных адаптеров много.

**Update**

Несмотря на указанный выше паттерн, никто не отменял и оптимизацию самого запроса. Настоятельно рекомендуется при написании запроса (того самого, который выдает `Cursor`) пользоваться интерактивной командой [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) - он по сути будет показывать как выполняется запрос и где узкие места в производительности. Исходя из него обычно либо надо изменять запрос, либо ставить индексы на поля/выражения. Без надлежащей оптимизации запроса - тормоза будут несмотря на все ухищрения на клиентской стороне Android

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я ещё присматриваюсь к варианту предложенному  посте на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/154931/ Идея: "мы запрашиваем только первичные ключи, а затем, при отображении каждой из строк, запрашиваем остальные столбцы по этому первичному ключу" Что думаете по его поводу?

Comment: Сразу видно, что писал статью человек плохо знакомый с особенностями SQL, тормоза не из-за этого, а из-за того, что запрос к БД неоптимизированный. Если написать правильный `select` с нужными индексами то скорость возрастет. Любой нормальный SQL'ист вам за 2 секунды скажет как надо оптимизировать запрос и как пользоваться инструментом `analyze/explain query`

Comment: Используя библиотеку RecyclerViewCursorAdapter либо не используя её, после пролистывания списка примерно до 5000 элемента, приложение падает с ошибкой: "IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 0 failed" Верояно из-за ограничения CursorWindow http://stackoverflow.com/a/6721886